# Why won't this.$el work in my backbone view?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

The biggest problem I have with backbone is that I never seem to grasp how "el" works. I feel like I truly do know how it is supposed to work, but it always seems to give me trouble.

Why is this.$el undefined in this codepen example?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gPdyvj?editors=0010

the html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="todo-container">
    <h1>To Do List</h1>
    <input type="text" class="new-todo-box">
    <button class="test">test</button>
    <div class="todo-list">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

the javascript

```
  var TodoView = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    el: '.todo-container',
    events: {
        'click .test': 'handleEnter'
    },
    handleEnter: function(){
        console.log("hello world test. ")
    },

    initialize: function(){
      this.render();
    },

    render: function(){
        console.log("hello")

      //this.$el is undefined
      console.log(this.$el)

      //so this does not work. 
      this.$el.html("testing $el")


    }

  });

$(document).ready(function(){  
  new TodoView();
});
```

I don't get it because I am defining what the el element is using the class name. I am pretty sure I have used it like this in the past. I feel like I never know when el is going to work correctly. The events are also not firing and I think it is related to el not being set correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the problem:

```
var TodoView = Backbone.Collection.extend({ // });
```

You are trying to make a "View" extending from a collection, and a collection don't have the attribute $el, instead of that, you must do:

```
var TodoView = Backbone.View.extend({ // });
```

Comment: ahh crap. didn't catch that. This is a stupid question now. thanks lol

Comment: @SpencerCooley  you may consider using typescript for catching such mistakes early ;)